# How install libcairo2 (>= 1.12.0) in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, monodevelop, cairo

i want to install `libcairo2` (>= 1.12.0) on my `12.04 LTS`.
I need this package for `monodevelop` package. Any idea?

```
 rafael@rafael-note:~/Downloads/cairo-1.12.0$ sudo apt-get install
 monodevelop Reading package lists...Done 
 Building dependency tree    
 Reading state information... Done 
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
 situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
 required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
 Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  monodevelop :
 Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.12.0) but 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3 is to be
 installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
 packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -l 'monodevelop*' | grep '^ii'`

Answer (score 2):

`monodevelop` packages depend on `libcairo2` version `1.12.0` or grater but `Ubuntu 12.04` have `1.10.2-6` version (you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcairo2&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all)) so you have to manually download and install from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libcairo2/download) or [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cairo/).

```
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cairo/libcairo2_1.14.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i libcairo2_1.14.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

download version according to your system configuration (`64bit` or `32bit` )
if it still show any dependency then try command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: `libcairo2 breaks libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (<< 2.4.5-2~)` -- cannot install on 12.04